# Issue with adaptivity on Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile, xamarin.android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtilW.jpg)

Before I start, I wanted to mention that, sadly, my English is not the best, so if you find any mistakes, I apologize. Now, onto the main topic: I am a young student from Ukraine, currently enrolled in my university education. This year, our university assigned us a task: to create a team project. I, along with a couple of guys, decided to develop a Simple Bluetooth Chat App using Xamarin.Forms, despite having no prior experience in mobile development (but we do know C#).

From the beginning, everything seemed fine, but over time, we encountered some serious issues with basic functionalities and main features.

Our "searching skills" may not be the best, but we are trying hard—some things work, some don't. However, we are currently stuck on a few things and would be extremely grateful for your help, be it advice, links to relevant topics, or code snippets.

Feel free to ask questions or reach out if you need more information, including my part of the code or screenshots.

Here are one of the current problems:

**Adaptivity**: Everything looks okay on our emulation device, but not on real ones. Perhaps Xamarin.Forms has some universal methods to ensure consistency across all devices.In our application, all pages are made using grid, we could not find a working solution for the adaptation to work on different devices, let's look at an example on one of the pages, this is the Privacy Policy page, the most simple one, this is the reason why we use it for example. We will pin the pics bellow. Actually, we have some kind of visual problems almost at everyone page.

For understanding we also will pin xaml page code.

I hope we get some assistance here, and I wish everyone a nice day!

We read documentation and everywhere use Grid with Auto and * properties + we also use Stack Layout... We can't get it why it's looks so awful at real devices

CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage  
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:B_Hedge"
    x:Class="B_Hedge.PrivacyPolicy">
    
    <Grid x:Name="BackgroundField" Background="{StaticResource FromRightLightTheme}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Clicked="GoBack" Source="{local:ImageResource B_Hedge.AddedFiles.Media.GoBack.png}" 
                     HeightRequest="48" WidthRequest="48" CornerRadius="360" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="2" BackgroundColor="White"
                     HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="8" Margin="8, 8, 0, 0"/>
        
        <Frame  Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" BackgroundColor="#A9DCF5" CornerRadius="16"  HasShadow="True"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="8, 32, 8, 0">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Privacy Policy" TextColor="Black" FontFamily="ExtraBold" FontSize="32"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                <Label  Text="{StaticResource PrivacyPolicyText}"
                        TextColor="Black" FontFamily="SemiBold" FontSize="16"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="Last Update was added 20.10.2023 by The B-Hedge Team" 
               TextDecorations="Underline" TextColor="Black" FontFamily="ExtraBold" FontSize="12"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="End" Margin="0, 0, 0, 8"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: releavant code needs to be posted in the body of the post, not as a link to an offsite resource

Comment: why is the Frame in the same row as the image?  And spanning all three rows?  That would be the first thing I would try

Comment: @Jason added code inside body. 

Otherwise it's not enough space for text inside the frame

Comment: this is a pretty basic issue.  The real device has less available real estate than the emulator.  You need to take that into account when designing your layouts

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your question according to your code. For real device, you can try the following code to fix adaptation problem:

```xml
<ScrollView>
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" ..../>
        
        <!-- remove Grid.RowSpan="3" -->
        <Frame Grid.Row="1">
            <StackLayout>
                .....
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        
        <Label Grid.Row="2" .../>
    </Grid>
    
</ScrollView>
```

Hope it can help you :)

Comment: Your advice did not work, now the bottom line is not displayed at all on a real device and the page with text is cut off even more

What do you think about this? Perhaps there is another solution?

I wanted to add pics for better understanding but how I could see I can't do it, sadly...

Comment: here is the link for better understanding: [![temp-Imagec-Cp7-Cw.jpg](https://i.postimg.cc/NjGKzC2Q/temp-Imagec-Cp7-Cw.jpg)](https://postimg.cc/BXyZ8gCz) *added pics via link*

Comment: here is the code how it looks like: https://codeshare.io/MN7wYO

Comment: I have read the [code](https://codeshare.io/MN7wYO) you provided. Have you forgotten to add [`ScrollView`](https://imgur.com/a/PdzYFon)?  Its [role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview) is to allow you to roll the view, in order to avoid insufficient space.

Comment: Actually, I don't think what we need this. Just check the pics, our text isn't so big

Comment: But we will try and check it on real device